# How to type functions that return properties of objects based on argument provided?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

If we had a function that returned a property value from an object given the object and a string property name as argument, how would we write type definitions for it?

```
const obj = {
    name: 'Hello',
    age: 32,
};

function getProp<OBJ>(obj: OBJ, propname: keyof OBJ): DONT_KNOW_TYPE {
    return obj[propname];
}

const name = getProp(obj, 'name');
```

How do we properly type the return value such that the property type of the property requested by the propname argument is enforced? Essentially, what should go in place of `DONT_KNOW_TYPE`?

Of course `any` and `OBJ[keyof OBJ]` are possible but it doesn't specifically enforce the type of the property stated in the second argument, and by default typescript infers that the return type of the function is a union of all the property types in `OBJ` which is less than desireable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make `propname`'s type a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter like `K extends keyof OBJ` (well, `T`, not `OBJ`, because `OBJ` is not a conventional type parameter name), and then use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to represent the property type: `T[K]`.

This looks very close to the `getProperty()` function shown in the [(now deprecated) documentation for indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
  return o[propertyName]; // o[propertyName] is of type T[K]
}
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
const name = getProperty(obj, 'name');
// const name: string
console.log(name.toUpperCase()); // "HELLO"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANAmgLSQbwFBKXgHtgoAXJIgIwCskBeHfApUSALiQHIAJCAG35EuAGmYEQAcwicAzACYxBAL4BuXMwBmAV2DwyASxJJpZAAoAnIjAgWyATwA8AFRFIA0kggAPMhGAAJlBIANYQ9kSaSM4AfAAURJyuSDBWNnb2AHLgMh4AlEkA2u4AukwsSBYQZNoWwJSFqda2DtmQJapIAPRdDU3prTllBsGRSA420cUlzMoaBMSkFGzIjKaWzRkJtG5cK1x56gQ9hCTkrDmc5BYGwJLMi1BE-BAAdEKScSuvZEQAqjB0gBhEBQCBxPKHbq9ABEPAAogAZREAeRhGmUQA)

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
    name: 'Hello',
    age: 32,
} as const;

function getProp<T extends typeof obj, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, propname: K): T[K] {
    return obj[propname];
}

const name = getProp(obj, 'name');
```